# Local location notifications are not being delivered in iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, location

I have an app which uses UNLocationNotificationTrigger to deliver notification based on user's location. When I'm testing my app sometimes it registers that user entered specific region, but doesn't deliver notification on entering region. Other times it works perfectly but I was wondering why this doesn't work every time. Does anyone else have similar problem? I would appreciate if someone could give a short explanation on this problem :)

This is the piece of code for registering notification:

```
let notification = UNMutableNotificationContent()

notification.title = "Notification title"
notification.subtitle = "Notification subtitle"
notification.body = "Notification body"

let notificationTrigger = UNLocationNotificationTrigger(region: enteredRegion, repeats: true)
let notificationRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "id12494", content: notification, trigger: notificationTrigger)

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(notificationRequest, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```